# MariaDB JSON datatype issue

Tags: json, mariadb

I am going to use MariaDB JSON column in my table and its `CREATE TABLE` is below:

```
CREATE TABLE events( 
  id int auto_increment primary key, 
  event_name varchar(255), 
  visitor varchar(255), 
  properties json, 
  browser json
);
```

Now I am trying to pull values out of the JSON columns using the column path operator ( ->) as below:

```
SELECT id, browser->'$.name' browser
FROM events;
```

But its not working for me and this is the error message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near '>'$.name' browser FROM events' at line 1

Can anybody tell me what this message says and how to fix this?
Hope somebody may help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Why? Why? Why? If you need to work with the data you are storing, why are you hiding it away in a JSON string? Creating proper columns will make it much easier to search, filter and update.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular there are *occasionally* good reasons to use JSON, but overall I agree, data that needs to be referenced regularly should have its own column.

Comment: I updated your tags and question title to make it more clear you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. MariaDB forked from MySQL in 2010 and it has been diverging slowly. These are two different products now, and they should not be assumed to be compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB doesn't support the `->` shorthand for `JSON_EXTRACT` that MySQL does (see the comments on the [manual page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_extract/), it's an open [feature request](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13594#)), so you need to use `JSON_EXTRACT`:

```sql
SELECT id, JSON_EXTRACT(browser, '$.name') browser
FROM events;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=bea088be81936bc806a51cd0adaa1c8f)

Comment: Hello Nick, Is there any MariaDB workaround for MySQL inline path operator (->>) ? Reason is  just I need to remove surrounded quote marks from result.

Comment: @ugnuku you should wrap the `JSON_EXTRACT` in `JSON_UNQUOTE` to emulate `->>` e.g. `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(browser, '$.name'))`